# Firestore: Query names that match or similar to the searched term

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of users with their names in the Firestore database. What I am trying to achieve is to make users able to search and find other users. My problem is that:

```
Query query = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("name", searchTerm);
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserObject> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserObject>()
                .setQuery(query, UserObject.class)
                .build();
```

In the code above, I am able to find users only if I write their first and last name exactly right. But what I want is to get users that do have similar names or last names. And also, users' last and first names are stored in one string variable. Like in facebook, if you search some names, it will display the similar names as well. Is there a good way to achieve that with firestore?

Comment: I think your best shot is to download the whole collection, and iterate through each entry and apply your regular expression logic to each one. This way you can process the list again when typing new name without hitting the cloud too much

Comment: Hmm yeah, I was thinking about it too. I hope its not gonna be a lot of work for the processor when the database gets large

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search):

> Cloud Firestore doesn't support native indexing or search for text fields in documents. Additionally, downloading an entire collection to search for fields client-side isn't practical.

So I strongly recommend you not to download the entire collection in order to create a search, isn't worth it. But in order to have a slightly better search, I recommend you use the following query:

```
Query query = db.collection("users").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText+ "\uf8ff");
```

If this query isn't what you are searching for, I recommend you use [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) search, which is also recommended by Firebase. I also recommend you see this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)**.

Comment: Hey Alex, I checked your video. Nice. I will try to implement Algolia. What is \uf8ff means?

Answer (score 4):

Late answer but for anyone who's still looking for an answer try this.

```
Query query = db.collection("users").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", searchTerm);
```